# Make allotment panels without scrollbar

Tags: css, reactjs, height

I would like to make a draggable split panel by https://github.com/johnwalley/allotment.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-qrb8jw?file=App.tsx,style.css,index.tsx

I notice that because of the CSS style: `.container { height: 100vh; overflow: scroll; }`, there is a scrollbar on the right of the output.

But if we delete `className="container"`, the allotment will not render.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Allotment vertical>
        <Allotment.Pane>Main Area</Allotment.Pane>
        <Allotment.Pane>abc</Allotment.Pane>
      </Allotment>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Does anyone know how to render an allotment that occupies 100% of the height of the screen and does not cause a scrollbar on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try reset the default margins to prevent unnecessary spacing, and also specify `overflow` property not to show scorllbars by default in CSS.

Forked example with modification: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-tuwkpe?file=style.css)

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  /*  Can also be "overflow: auto" if prefer to show scrollbars when content overflows */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```